# Uploading image into the non-header part of infowindow in #Cartodb

Tags: carto, infowindow

There are instructions on uploading image into the infowindow header in CartoDB. however, I would like to upload an image into the sub categories under CartoDB and encountered problems.

What is the procedure to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the HTML of the infowindows in the Custom HTML option. Then, inthe cartodb-popup-content you could add something like:

```
  <h4>Use other columns or your text here</h4>
  <p>Extra text, this is my {{name}}</p>
  <img src="{{url_column}}" width="50%">
```